# Assign ("Months-days-hours") to a LocalDate variable

Tags: java, mysql, localdate

After a lot of tries I didn't found a way to assign a date taken from sql to a `LocalDate` variable in a pattern of ("MM-dd-hh"). I have defined a timestamp field(it goes from years to seconds) which I need to set a prenotation hour, day and month. What do you suggest?

```
public class Prenot {

    private LocalDate date;

    private Date datesql;

    public Prenot(LocalDate date) {

        this.date = date;
    }


    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return this.date;

    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }





    public static void visualizePrenot(Connection con,
            ObservableList<Prenot> list) {
        try {
            Connessione connn = new Connessione();
            FXMLDocumentController prova = new FXMLDocumentController();
            connn.estabilishConn(prova.getUser(), prova.getPass());
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prenotazione");

            while (rs.next()) {

                list.add(new Prenot(
rs.getDate("data").toLocalDate());

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

edit: I focused the code to needs,
Now what do you suggest, if I abandon the java.sql.Date, to get a TIMESTAMP value from a mysql db? And if so what do you think it's better to get, into another different getter, days and hours and show them in a TableView?

Comment: What problem exactly are you experiencing? And what did you try so far?

Comment: what is the datatype of your field that stores the date in the format `MM-dd-hh`?

Comment: (a) What is 'prenotation'? (b) You are expected to minimize your code example here on Stack Overflow to demonstrate your core issue, not cut-and-paste production code for us to wade through. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (c) Date-time objects contain data/information, not strings and so do not have a 'format'. Already discussed in hundreds (thousands?) of existing Questions and Answers already posted on Stack Overflow. Search this site thoroughly before posting.

Comment: Sorry for coping the entire class, I wanted to be clear with the code. However, i tried e getter like this:
    public LocalDate getDate(){

Comment: Sorry for coping the entire class, I wanted to be clear with the code. However, what do you suggest, if I abandon the java.sql.Date, to get a TIMESTAMP value from a mysql db? And if so what do you think it's better to get, into another different getter, days and hours and show them in a TableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day (hours). You may think of it as year, month and day of month. If you need to store hours too, two options come to mind:

- The standard solution is to store a timestamp in the database and use an `Instant` in Java. Then convert the `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` when you need to display it to a user in some time zone.
- Alternatively you may use a `LocalDateTime` in Java.

In either case there is no need for a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. With a sufficiently new JDBC driver (from Connector/J version 5.1.37 or so, I think) you can directly store a `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` into the database and retrieve them as the same type again. If you really insist on using the outdated `java.sql` types, you need a `Timestamp` since a `java.sql.Date` doesn’t handle hour of day either.

Disclaimer: It’s all something I’ve read, not something I have tried myself in practice.

Answer (score 0):

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/LocalDate.html) does not store the time component.

Most likely you need [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/LocalDateTime.html), in which case you could try

```
LocalDateTime l = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSeconds(t.getTime() / 1000)
```

**EDIT**: as @Ole-v-v notes in the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818424/assign-months-days-hours-to-a-localdate-variable/44820257#comment76644414_44820257), `ofEpochSeconds` requires two more arguments, for example

```
LocalDateTime l = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSeconds(t.getTime() / 1000,0, ZoneOffet.UTC);
```

Comment: (I acknowledge the correction so have deleted my prevous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

        System.out.println("Before : " + now);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);

        System.out.println("After : " + formatDateTime);
```

Hope that helps!!!